# how to open specific Jframe as a main jframe?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

[image]

when I run the project compiler says BUILD SUCCESSFUL but not any window is appear. when I runt the project I want to start main_window as a default window. but I have no Idea how to setting up this.

Comment: Set that class to be the main class in the project? is this what you are asking?

Comment: I am new to java. It may be that. I don't know what is the main class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating a jar file (as I assume you will be doing from your previously deleted question), the main class would be specified by the jar file's manifest.

e.g., the manifest file, named `MANIFEST.MF` could contain a line looking like:

```
Main-Class: gui.main_window
```

Comment: yes, Im trying to create jar file. actually I create jar file distribution. when I double click it no window is appear. 

where can I find manifest ?

Comment: @SelaruSinbath: the manifest should be in the META-INF directory. There may be other reasons why no window is showing. Run the jar file from the command line to see if any errors or exceptions are produced.

Comment: I ran the jar file as "java -jar project2014_v4.0.jar" but nothing happen. no compile errors.

netbeans has button called "run project"(F6) when I press that button output window shows BUILD SUCCESSFUL. but no window is appear. can you recommend to do something

Comment: I restart my machine and ran it again in cmd. new I there was a message like this "Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit."

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels and @ylun thank you you both, Its about setting up main class
I found the answer [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CP6V1T74q3Q) in youtube and it works fine same as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on the Netbeans `tool-bar`. An drop down menu should appear. Select `Customize` and scroll down through the options until you see `Run File`. Drag the button onto the `tool-bar`. Now select the `main_window.java` and hit the `Run File` button.

The IDE should run only the file.